# What is wrong with this template declaration?

Tags: c++

```
template<class T> void Insert(T*, T) { *T = T; }
```

produces error

> ```
> "T: illegal use of this type as an expression"
> ```

Comment: T is a type not a variable.

Comment: Try it with a normal function; same issue. `void insert(int*, int) { *int = int; }`

Answer (score 2):

The body of this function template tries to dereference and assign the type `T`. This is not possible, you need to change it to

```
template<class T> void insert(T* t1, T t2)
{
    *t1 = t2;
}
```